# how to set a JSON object equal to another JSON object within the parent's declaration

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-messenger

I'm new to javascript and json and messing around with some code.

This is the format of my JSON object

```
messageData = {
     "attachment": {
         "type": "template",
         "payload": {
             "template_type": "generic",
             elements: [{
                 title: "titleOne",
                 subtitle: "subtitleOne"
             }, {
                 title: "titleTwo",
                 subtitle: "subtitleTwo"
             }]
         }
     }
 }
```

Instead of going in an individually adding each title and subtitle object to elements I want to do this with a loop and just set one object equal to an array that contains many more numbers of title and subtitle objects. So lets say I have the object titles:

```
titles = {} //100 objects with different titles and subtitles.
```

Is there a way to implement this logic shown below?

```
 messageData = {
            "attachment": {
                "type": "template",
                "payload": {
                    "template_type": "generic", 
                     elements = titles
                } 
            }
        }
```

Correctly formatting everything? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you clarify what your `titles` object/array looks like? Can't you just assign `titles` to `elements`?

Comment: Are you trying to copy the array, but use the same `{title, subtitle}` objects? Or do you need to clone the whole structure?

Comment: @mjsarfatti Titles is an array of multiple objects containing title and subtitle objects. And yes that's what I was thinking. but i'm not sure how to assign it. Is it as simple as "elements" = titles ?

Comment: @nrabinowitz I want to copy the array with the same {title, subtitle} structure and just set it equal to "elements" instead manually setting each index of titles one after another

Comment: Then what you wrote is already your answer :) `elements: titles`. Ps: no need to double quote property names in this case.

Comment: This looks like a FB messenger generic template. Please note that the template can only support a maximum of 10 elements (See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable `titles` which has an *array* of *objects* assigned to it. Something like:

```
var titles = [{...}, {...}, ...];
```

You later want to assign this array (currently assigned to the variable `titles`) to a *property* of an *object* (in this case `elements`):

```
var messageData = {
    attachment: {
        type: "template",
        payload: {
            template_type: "generic", 
            elements // <-- here
        } 
    }
}
```

(Please note that I removed double quotes from the *property names*, they are not necessary as they have a valid notation)

As you suspected, nothing is easier than this:

```
var messageData = {
    attachment: {
        type: "template",
        payload: {
            template_type: "generic", 
            elements: titles
        } 
    }
}
```

This would be enough as an answer, but let's take a small step back now: in javascript pretty much everything is an *object* (I'm simplifying a little bit here, strings are not objects for example, but I invite you to find out more by yourself). But yes, as confusing as it sounds at first, an *array* is an *object*.

Another thing to know is that in javascript objects are assigned by reference. This means that if you modify the original `titles` array, the `elements` array would be modified as well. They are just two names pointing at the very same object.

In your particular case this detail might not matter, but if you want to separate the lives of `titles` and `elements` you need to *clone* the original array, before you assign it again. And the fastest way is passing through a JSON conversion:

```
var titles_0 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(titles));
var messageData = {
    attachment: {
        type: "template",
        payload: {
            template_type: "generic", 
            elements: titles_0
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!